# Targetting attributes in XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have the following xml:

```
<Head>
    <Group1>
        <Ref>
            <RefType>ABC123</RefType>
            <RefIdentifier>123456789</RefIdentifier>
            <RefDate>2013-11-30</RefDate>
        </Ref>
    </Group1>
    <Group2>
        <UOM>
            <UOMType>XYZ789</UOMType>
            <UOMIdentifier>BlahBlah</UOMIdentifier>
        </UOM>
    </Group2>
    <Group3>
        <Rec>
            <RecType>XYZ789</RecType>
            <RecIdentifier>HalbHalb</RecIdentifier>
        </Rec>
    </Group3>
</Head>
```

that I need to transform into:

```
<Head>
    <Ref>
      <Identifier type="ABC123">123456789</Identifier>
      <RefDate>2013-11-30</RefDate>
    </Ref>
    <UOM>
      <Identifier type="XYZ789">BlahBlah</Identifier>
    </UOM>
    <Rec>
      <Identifier type="XYZ789">HalbHalb</Identifier>
    </Rec>
</Head>
```

using xslt. So far I have the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Head"/>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="Head">
        <Head>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group1/Ref">
                <Ref>
                    <Identifier><xsl:value-of select="RefIdentifier"/></Identifier>
                    <RefDate><xsl:value-of select="RefDate"/></RefDate> 
                </Ref>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group2/UOM">
                <UOM>
                    <Identifier><xsl:value-of select="UOMIdentifier"/></Identifier> 
                </UOM>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group3/Rec">
                <Rec>
                    <Identifier><xsl:value-of select="RecIdentifier"/></Identifier> 
                </Rec>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Head>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives me

```
<Head>
    <Ref>
        <Identifier>123456789</Identifier>
        <RefDate>2013-11-30</RefDate>
    </Ref>
    <UOM>
        <Identifier>BlahBlah</Identifier>
    </UOM>
    <Rec>
        <Identifier>HalbHalb</Identifier>
    </Rec>
</Head>
```

but I don't know how to get the 'type' attribute and its value in the 'Identifier' tags for the Ref, UOM, and Rec tags. How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like your title is incorrect: you're trying to transform XML, not XSL, using XSLT. Also the title should be more specific: transforming XML using XSLT is a whole genre of questions.

Comment: P.S. Welcome to stackoverflow. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't know how to get the 'type' attribute and its value in the
>   'Identifier' tags for the Ref, UOM, and Rec tags. How can I do this?

Use:

```
<Identifier type="{RefType}"><xsl:value-of select="RefIdentifier"/></Identifier>
```

The curly braces are an Attribute Value Template, which lets you substitute the value of the XPath expression inside them. They are only allowed in certain attribute values in an XSLT stylesheet, but one common place to use them is in literal result elements.

FYI: `Ref`, `UOM`, and `Rec` are not "tags" but elements. They are serialized using start and end tags, but XSLT doesn't operate on the tags; it operates on the elements. Thinking and talking about them in terms of tags is like saying "I owe Steve's hand $5" instead of "I owe Steve $5". I'm not trying to be pedantic, but thinking of the XML as a tree of nodes, where each element is a single node instead of two separated tags, will help you better understand how stylesheets work. XSLT transforms a tree to another tree, and the serialization to tags only happens after the stylesheet is finished; sometimes the XSLT doesn't even have any control over the serialization.

Comment: P.S. Bob's approach using `<xsl:attribute>` is also valid. But if you're already using a literal result element for `<Identifier>`, instead of `<xsl:element>`, there's usually no reason to use the more verbose `<xsl:attribute>` instead of a literal result attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attribute` tag:

```
<Identifier>
  <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="RefType"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="RefIdentifier"/>
</Identifier>
```

This inserts the type as an attribute.